# wpa_supplicant doesn't get new IP when re-associate?

Tags: debian, wifi, dhcp, wpa-supplicant, wlan

I am struggling to setup my wlan so it can re-associate to another hotspot and renew its IP automatically. I have found a [similar question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/235257/why-wpa-supplicant-doesnt-get-new-ip-when-reassociate) but nobody responded.

I am using Debian stretch. The first association works fine but when the WiFi re-associates with another hotspot (for whatever reason (e.g. first hotspot gets shutdown)) the IP stays the same. If I manually run `dhclient wlan0` the IP will refresh. But I want it to be automatic.

Here is my `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
allow-hotplug eth0

auto wlan0
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
iface default inet dhcp
```

`/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf` contains:

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1

network={
    ssid="FrstHotspot"
    psk="some password"
}

network={
    ssid="SecondHotspot"
    psk="some password"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As for your `/etc/network/interfaces`, I think it has to be something similar to this to work with your current configuration:

```
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
wpa-driver wext
wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
iface default inet dhcp
```

You are defining the interface has dhcp, which then enters in conflict with the `wpa_supplicant` that invokes DHCP. In that way, `wpa_supplicant` loses the ability to signal when the ssid/network was changed, and so the IP address does not change when changing networks/ssids.

You can also define priorities in the `wpa_supplicant.conf` on the ssid to use as in:

> ```
> ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev  
> update_config=1
>
> network={  
> ssid="FrstHotspot"  
> psk="some password" 
> priority = 10  
> }
>
> network={  
> ssid="SecondHotspot"  
> psk="some password" 
> priority = 20  
> }
> ```

The higher the priority, that will be the `ssid` that will be tried first.

Some content of https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/wireless-cli.md states:

> If you have two networks in range, you can add the priority option to
>   choose between them. The network in range, with the highest priority,
>   will be the one that is connected.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. I have already set a higher priority for one hotspot ("FrstHotspot"). The fact is when my device is connected to "FrstHotspot" and then  this hotspot shutdown, it will reassociate to "SecondHotspot" but keep the same IP. For now, I have to manually do `dhclient wlan0` ( for example to access the device by ssh). I am searching a solution to automatically do a `dhclient` when the device reassociate to another hotspot

Comment: I edit the answer with corrections to your interfaces file, which I had forgot.

Comment: Adding driver information doesn't change the behavior. But removing `allow-hotplug wlan0` will keep the interface down at startup. Perhaps I am not explaining well what I want. [The question in this thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/235257/why-wpa-supplicant-doesnt-get-new-ip-when-reassociate) is exactly what I am experiencing.

Comment: In the interfaces file, it has to be manual. The DHCP must be handled by wpa_config

Comment: If I set it to manual I got : `wlan0: association with <mac_address> timed out`

Comment: Changed it. Would you try it now? Dont add there the `auto wlan0` directive.

Comment: This doesn't work too. It connects at startup but none IP is assigned and i can't connect throught ssh or ping it (even if the hotspot show the device with an IP). When I shutdown the firsthotspot, the device times out trying to connect to secondhotspot. Reactivating the first hotspot will result to device connecting to it... but still no ip address is assigned (`ip a`)

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer: `wpa_supplicant` by itself only manages authentication on WLAN interfaces. `dhclient` is run by another layer, either the traditional `ifup`/`ifdown` or others like network manager. `wpa_supplicant` can send a signal to the other layer, but the other layer must be configured for that.

So the first step is to find out what kind of network management you have installed (Debian supports several). Then you need to configure it.

The `wpa_supplicant` documentation also to have a document on roaming access, this may also contain hints how to correctly setup ifup/ifdown for automatic reconnect. Look in `/usr/share/doc/`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @dirkt. How to figure out wich network manager I am using? At first, my debian comes with connman but I disable it to setup the wpa_supplicant only.